# GWT1.5.3 application not loading in chrome

Tags: javascript, gwt

We have a huge GWT application which was working perfectly good in IE and chrome, but from few days it stopped working in chrome. In the developer console of chrome it says "Top identifier duplicated in *.cache.html"

I tried compiling the code only for chrome i.e putting the user agent as safari, even after this the issue still remains same.

This time i compiled the code with style as Pretty and it works good in chrome but the problem with this is *.cache.html bulks up to 9mb from 2mb, which leads to performance issues.

If the GWT compile style is OBF, the compiler is not able to generate proper scripts for chrome.

some one help me in coming out of this problem.

Comment: If you persist in using a 10 year old version your are going to get into troubles in the end. I don't suspect that another answer than 'upgrade GWT' will come in this thread.

Comment: Update GWT version, it should be painless. I know that sometimes on legacy app or big companies there is a huge pushback on updates but seems like it's necessary. I did this kid of stuff many times, post more if you need any support.

Comment: Even GWT 2.6.x is not fully compatible with latest versions of Chrome anymore (e.g. `Window.getScrollTop()`, `Element.getAbsoluteTop()`, etc. are broken on Chrome 61+), so I can't even imagine what it must be like to try to make GWT 1.5.3 work. Just upgrade to 2.8.x.

Comment: I'd clarify Knarf's statement slightly - if you persist in using a 10 year old browser toolkit _on bleeding edge browsers_, you are going to encounter issues, though I suspect it has no major issues on old browsers. Remember too that Chrome itself had only even existed for a month when GWT 1.5.3 was released.